# How to determine the tasks running on a node in Apache Storm

Tags: grouping, apache-storm

I want to write a CustomGrouping which propagates the emissions of one bolt to another bolt running on the same node. The localOrShuffleGrouping partially achieves this by trying to retain the tuples within the same process. I want to go one step further and put a bound at a machine level. The primary intention here is to reduce network latency and thus increase throughput (by not being limited by bandwidth).

I am aware that you can obtain the taskIDs running in the same worker process by calling getThisWorkerTasks() from TopologyContext. However, I could not find a way of getting all the taskIDs running on the same node (including that of other processes).

Answer (score 0):

I think we haven't API to do this. One way for doing this is that down stream bolts send their host name (or IP) and taskId to all upstream bolts (by global streaming) and with this info in upstream bolt you can determine the best bolt to send tuple. For sending the host name  you can use tick tuple.

Comment: Thank you Rahim! I was thinking about this too and I felt this might end up increasing network traffic as I will be doing global grouping. Ofcourse, I will have to run some benchmarks before concluding.

Comment: I think it doesn't necessary to send host info each time. The first time is sufficient so it doesn't impact network traffic.

Comment: Is it? So once the worker process spawns the executors and generates the taskIDs, will they remain the same throughout? Even when if the executor starts working on another bolt later?

Comment: Each executor runs tasks of one bolt or spout. I mean you can send host info for one time when bolt started and it doesn't need to send these info frequently.